# vertex ai pipeline: label not populating on billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to trace how much each pipeline I run on vertex costs. I read about adding labels that lets me filter my billing report based on the [labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels).

It says that vertex ai is supported and the api shows the same with a labels kwarg.

```
job = aiplatform.PipelineJob(display_name = 'inference',
                                    template_path = tmpdirname + '/' + "inference.json",
                                    enable_caching = True,
                                    project = 'project id',
                                    location = "europe-west4",    
                                    parameter_values=params,
                                    credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('service.json'),
                                    labels={'pipeline':job_id}
```

The pipeline starts and runs through without issue. The label is on the job and I can within the vertex AI pipelines console filter for the job as well. On the billing dashboard it still doesn't exist, when I export the data to bigquery it doesn't exist, I can see the cost for those pipelines I ran but I cannot see those labels and filter on them.

has anyone managed to get the label filter to work for vertex ai so that you can see the cost of a pipeline job?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently bumped into the same issue, I think Vertex AI have an active entry for this in the bugtracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193522968

I ended up finding a contact at Google, they promised to release the fix in the end of September.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is now resolved as every Vertex pipeline is provided automatically with a label called `vertex-ai-pipelines-run-billing-id` which can be cross-referenced with billing data. In our Vertex project this has existed since 17th Nov 22. The same resolution is mentioned in the linked bug tracker.